# Angular2 ngIf stops running

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having an issue with (what I believe to be) change detection. Excuse my ignorance as I'm somewhat new to angular2.

So I have the following code in my view. Basically its generating these cards for every event that I pull in. When the user hits a button, the *ngIf is supposed to hide/show the buttons based on the values I get back from a couple of functions (basically checking if the user has already registered/clicked that button).

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let event of events" text-wrap>
                <ion-card-header>
                    <span class="title">{{event.title}}</span>
                    <span *ngIf="doesExist(event.startDate)" class="date">{{formatDateDisplay(event)}}</span>
                </ion-card-header>
                <img src='{{event.imageURL}}'/>
                <ion-card-content [innerHTML]="event.desc"></ion-card-content>

                <ion-list *ngIf="doesExist(event.sgOptions)" radio-group [ngModel]="event.sgOptions" [formControl]="sgOption">
                  <ion-list-header>
                    Select Preferred Time
                  </ion-list-header>
                  <ion-item *ngFor="let opt of event.sgOptions">
                    <ion-label>{{opt}}</ion-label>
                    <ion-radio [value]="opt" [disabled]="!isNotRegistered(event.id) && !isSudentProfileBlank()"></ion-radio>
                  </ion-item>
                </ion-list>

                <ion-buttons end>
                      <button block primary *ngIf="isNotRegistered(event.id)" (click)="submitToSheet(event.title, event.id, doesExist(event.sgOptions))">Sign Me Up</button>
                      <button block primary *ngIf="!isNotRegistered(event.id) && !isSudentProfileBlank()" disabled>Signed Up!</button>
                      <button block primary *ngIf="!isNotRegistered(event.id) && isSudentProfileBlank()" (click)="openModal()">Sign Me Up</button>
                </ion-buttons>
            </ion-card>
```

After the user clicks the first button, it hides the active button and shows the disabled. That is the expected behavior. However, when I try to then click another, it doesn't hide/show the buttons appropriately. Upon inspecting in the browser, the *ngIf is simply no longer firing and checking my functions.

Any one know why that would no longer work? Is there another way I could get this done?

--**EDIT**--

Here is a link to the page in a github repo. Its an earlier version compared to the code I pasted, but the issue exists there too.

https://github.com/tjohnson5/Trav-Ionic2-App1/tree/master/app/pages/register

Comment: Can you post your component.ts code?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about that. Here is a link to the page in a github repo I made some time ago. Sorry if its kind of a mess right now...
https://github.com/tjohnson5/Trav-Ionic2-App1/tree/master/app/pages/register

Comment: Its hard to understand whats going on without seeing the behavior. If you are looping through a bunch of cards you may be dealing with a naming Convention issue where you need to make sure clickable elements etc are uniquely identified using index etc. Whenever I hear of apps having unexpected behaviors on click events etc. this is the first thing that comes to my mind especially with loops.

Comment: Well through my investigating, I think I can confidently say its not so much related to the click event. Lets say I have *ngIf="notEmpty()". If I set a breakpoint in my notEmpty() function, it repeatedly gets hit even without my action. Pretty sure this is expected as the ngIf is checking for changes. So when I click the first button, it appropriately does it's thing. Now after that, same breakpoint in notEmpty NEVER gets hit. Its like it stopped checking that value/function. Almost as if I need to somehow get it checking/running again... Does that make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you create a smaller example in plunkr of what you are trying to do? Sorry.

Comment: Angular 2 is a pain to setup in plunker but if you know angular 1 I created this to demonstrate what I think you are talking about? https://plnkr.co/edit/YX3IoJNFuq7iOY73UrHa?p=preview

Comment: Ha yea I have no experience with Plunker... Anyways I was actually able to kind of find the cause. I noticed with your plunk and with a bare-bones recreation of my page, the issue doesn't exist. It works perfectly. So it had to be some other thing in my function chain. I disabled/stubbed-out potential culprits until I was able to fix the issue. Turns out that when I popped an Ionic "toast" (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toast/ToastController/) message, it causes the ngIf to stop. No idea why at this time, but its a bug on their end (beta version). Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a prepared Plunker template available at the first link at this site https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html ("live example") also the Plunker editor provides a template for Angular2 TS under the "new" button.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks! I wasn't aware of that!